# How to remove file name extension in a loop with Make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Assume that there is a directory which contains `foo.c`, `bar.c` and `Makefile`. The content of `Makefile` is:

```
loop:
    @for f in $(wildcard *.c) ; do \
        echo $$f ; \
        echo $(basename $$f); \
    done
```

Running `make` prints out the following text:

```
bar.c
bar.c
foo.c
foo.c
```

What I want is:

```
bar.c
bar
foo.c
foo
```

So it seems that `basename` has no effect in this loop. How can I make `basename` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop is not working in **make**, it's a **bash** loop. If you want similar behavior in **make**eeze, you can have

```
loop:
    $(foreach f, $(wildcard *.c), \
    echo $f; \
    echo $(basename $f);)
```

Or even

```
loop:
    $(foreach f, $(wildcard *.c), \
    $(info $f) \
    $(info $(basename $f)))
```

The **bash**eese way to strip prefix is:

```
loop:
    @for f in $(wildcard *.c) ; do \
        echo $$f ; \
        echo $${f%.c} ; \
    done
```

Comment: The first code snippet gives the error `@echo: not found`. If `@` is removed, the error is gone.